# d3 csv - Cannot Form TREE LAYOUT

Tags: tree, d3.js, nodes, children

I m not able to form a Tree Layout with the data below. What do you think I m doing wrong? Tried many options none working...Appreciate your help..

```
var margin = {top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var dataD;
d3.csv("./Data/Data.csv", function(csv) {
    var nodesByName = {};
    dataD = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d) { return "main" })
                .key(function(d) { return d.source })
                .key(function(d) { return d.target })
                .rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length; })
                .entries(csv);

    var nodes = tree.nodes(dataD[0]);
    console.log(nodes)

    // Create the link lines.
    svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(csv)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", diagonal);

});
```

----------------end of code------------

```
///Data.csv --looks like this
source,target
Merged Market,Individual
Merged Market,Sub Connector
Merged Market,Group of 1
Merged Market,Group 2-50
Commercial Insured Market,51 to 499
Commercial Insured Market,500+
Commercial Insured Market,Students
Commercial Self Insured Market,Self Insured
Commercial Self Insured Market,Host
Government Programs,Senior
Government Programs,FEP
Government Programs,MSP
Municipal and Labor Market,Municipal
Municipal and Labor Market,Labor
Ancillary Products,Ancillary
Ancillary Products,Dental
Ancillary Products,Medicare Part D
Ancillary Products,Stand Alone RX
Ancillary Products,Stand Alone Mental Health
Ancillary Products,Stand Alone Vision
Ancillary Products,FEP Dental
Sales Admin,Sales Admin
```

---

The Console gives this output of nodes

```
[Object]
  0: Object
  depth: 0
  key: "main"
  values: Array[7]
  x: 210
  y: 0
  __proto__: Object
  length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

----------------------- notice 'x' ad 'y' values present above. But this is absent for children---

```
[Object]
0: Object
  depth: 0
  key: "main"
  values: Array[7]
  0: Object
     key: "Merged Market"
     values: Array[4]
     0: Object
         key: "Individual"
         values: 1
      __proto__: Object
     1: Object
         key: "Sub Connector"
         values: 1
      __proto__: Object
     2: Object
         key: "Group of 1"
         values: 1
      __proto__: Object
     3: Object
         key: "Group 2-50"
         values: 1
      __proto__: Object
  length: 4
  __proto__: Array[0]
  __proto__: Object
  1: Object
  2: Object
  3: Object
  4: Object
  5: Object
  6: Object
length: 7
__proto__: Array[0]
x: 210
y: 0
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

------ Becuase the 'x' and 'y' and 'depth' are not forming in for the children, the tree layout is not working and giving the following error

Comment: You didn't include the error it gave you

Comment: Error: Problem parsing d="M0,300CNaN,300 NaN,NaN NaN,NaN"

Comment: <path class="link" d="M0,300CNaN,300 NaN,NaN NaN,NaN"></path>